# What happens if everyone skips a review?

Tags: discussion, review

On some sites, a low number of people use the review queues (mainly the ones with a low number of users overall). Since the skip button means that I won't ever get to see that queue again, what happens if everyone presses "Skip" (for a post right between "ok" and "has to be improved" or one that is very technical/specific)?

I don't know if this has happened before, I just want to know what **would** happen.

Will the item stay in the queue forever or until a new 1K+ user reviews it? Or does the system automatically assume that it's ok after a certain number of people have skipped it or after a certain amount of time has passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the item will stay in the queue if 'everybody' chooses <kbd>Skip</kbd>. You can always go back to a review item you skipped to review it again.

Note that there are other reasons why an item can leave the queue, e.g. when all close votes on a question expire.

Comment: I can also see my skipped reviews. There's a checkbox at the bottom of the "history" tab.

Comment: Ah, you're right. For a moderator it just *looks* different.